# PhpPowerpoint set slide width and height (slide dimensions)

Tags: php, powerpoint, phppowerpoint, odp

I want to know if there is a way to create a ppt file with pre defined width and height rather than default one.

Comment: Please would you show what you have tried?

Comment: Have you checked `PHPPowerPoint_DocumentLayout::setDocumentLayout`, `PHPPowerPoint_DocumentLayout::setLayoutXmilli` or `PHPPowerPoint_DocumentLayout::setLayoutYmilli`? [Their source code can be found here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPowerPoint/blob/master/Classes/PHPPowerPoint/DocumentLayout.php)

Answer (score 4):

I've used this code to set it for the new PHPPresentation (newer PHPPowerpoint version).
Hope it helps..(replace path's with your phppresentation path's
and `width(1180)` and `height(768)` to suit yours

```
/*Standard library loaders */
require_once  'include/Common/src/Common/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\Common\Autoloader::register();

require_once 'include/PHPPowerPoint2/src/PhpPresentation/Autoloader.php';

\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Autoloader::register();
/*Standard library loaders */

use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\PhpPresentation;

use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\DocumentLayout;


$objPHPPowerPoint = new PhpPresentation();

$objPHPPowerPoint->getLayout()->setDocumentLayout(DocumentLayout::LAYOUT_CUSTOM, true)
->setCX( 1180,  DocumentLayout::UNIT_PIXEL)
->setCY( 768,  DocumentLayout::UNIT_PIXEL);
```

Answer (score 2):

[The answer of @user2633993](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32954499/975624) is still valid, though the code for setting the layout width and height has changed a bit, now you need to set an array containing the `cx` and `cy` keys, their values doesn't matter.

So the code needs to look something like this:

```
$objPHPPowerPoint->getLayout()->setDocumentLayout(['cx' => 1280, 'cy' => 700], true)
        ->setCX(1280, DocumentLayout::UNIT_PIXEL)
        ->setCY(700, DocumentLayout::UNIT_PIXEL);`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set width and height:

[Please see this tutorial](https://github.com/Feudum/phppowerpoint)

```
$objPHPPowerPoint = new PHPPowerPoint();
$currentSlide = $objPHPPowerPoint->getActiveSlide();
$shape = $currentSlide->createDrawingShape();
$shape = $currentSlide->createRichTextShape();
$shape->setHeight(300);
$shape->setWidth(600);
$shape->setOffsetX(170);
$shape->setOffsetY(180);
$shape->getAlignment()->setHorizontal( PHPPowerPoint_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER );
$textRun = $shape->createTextRun('Thank you for using PHPPowerPoint!');
$textRun->getFont()->setBold(true);
$textRun->getFont()->setSize(60);
$textRun->getFont()->setColor( new PHPPowerPoint_Style_Color( 'FFC00000' ) );
$objWriter = PHPPowerPoint_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPPowerPoint, 'PowerPoint2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.pptx', __FILE__));
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with [`PHPPowerpoint`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPowerPoint) though.